# In HTML every button, font look some vertically down not in middle

Tags: html, css

[image]

```css
.--float-left { 
    float: left; 
    width: 100%; 
}
.form-add-button {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px 49px 0px 49px;
    background-color: none;
    border: 1px solid #14cc7b;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: #14cc7b;
    line-height: 40px;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    /*display:table-cell;*/
    /*vertical-align:middle;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="--float-left">
 <a href="#" class="form-add-button">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New
 </a>
</div>
```

I have also some tricky problem here in 1080p display it looks good I mean vertically middle but in laptop screen 1366x768 it looks close to bottom just like attached image.

Comment: The code snippet looks fine to me, but if I had to guess I would says iths the `line-height:40px`.  Try removing or changing that.

Comment: @sn3ll you're right but when I do changes in line-height:33px it's going to fit in 1366x768 screen but I need to add media queries for other screens. I need some proper solution for all screen.

Comment: Sorry, can't really offer much more without being able to see the problem.  Again, this code snippet looks fine in any resolution on my screen.

Answer (score 0):

Define the button as a flexbox. Horizontal and vertical alignment are perfect.

```css
.--float-left { 
    float: left; 
    width: 100%; 
}
.form-add-button {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px 49px 0px 49px;
    background-color: none;
    border: 1px solid #14cc7b;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: #14cc7b;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 80px;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /*vertical-align:middle;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="--float-left">
 <a href="#" class="form-add-button">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you center vertically with line-height as you do in your example, the icon is placed visually above the text because the baseline of most icon-fonts differs from text-fonts. In most cases you can fix it by pull the icon 1px down with `position:relative` and `top:1px`. A more sleek solution would be to add `transform:translateY(1px)`. *(see attachet snippet)*

```css
body {
  margin: 2rem;
}

.--float-left { 
    float: left; 
    width: 100%; 
}
.form-add-button {
    background-color: none;
    border: 1px solid #14cc7b;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: #14cc7b;
    padding: 0 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

/* works in most cases of icon-fonts */
.form-add-button i {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#" class="form-add-button">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New
</a>
```